# Python script/GUI to generate positive/negative images for CascadeClassifier?

Tags: classification, image-classification

For the first time, I am playing around with a [Cascade Classifier](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html) with the OpenCV package (also new to the latter). I realized that it would probably be faster to write my own GUI/script to generate the needed positive and negative images from the set of images I have than to open each file in Photoshop or Paint, but I also suspect this has been done many times before.

In particular, I am looking for a GUI that lets users page through files in a directory and then use mouse clicks to draw rectangles on a particular image and have the coordinates of the rectangle recorded for later purposes. Any suggestions? If not, I'll  be sure to post a link when/if I finish this. It seems like something of general enough utility I am surprised I can't find it in the OpenCV package itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I wrote the script. It gave me an excuse to learn Tkinter. It's pasted below. Note this is a one-off, not a model of good programming practice! If anyone uses this and has bugs or suggestions, let me know. Here's the [git link](https://github.com/sunnysideprodcorp/CascadeImagesorter/) and model code is pasted below:

```
import Tkinter
import Image, ImageTk
from Tkinter import Tk, BOTH
from ttk import Frame, Button, Style
import cv2
import os
import time
import itertools

IMAGE_DIRECTORY =            # Directory of existing files
POSITIVE_DIRECTORY =         # Where to store 'positive' cropped images
NEGATIVE_DIRECTORY =         # Where to store 'negative' cropped images (generated automatically based on 'positive' image cropping
IMAGE_RESIZE_FACTOR =        # How much to scale images for display purposes. Images are not scaled when saved.

# Everything stuffed into one class, not exactly model programming but it works for now
class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, list_of_files, write_file):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)           
        self.parent = parent
        self.list_of_files = list_of_files
        self.write_file = write_file
        self.image = None
        self.canvas = None
        self.corners = []
        self.index = -1
        self.loadImage()
        self.initUI()
        self.resetCanvas()


    def loadImage(self):
        self.index += 1
        img = cv2.imread(self.list_of_files[self.index])            
        print(self.list_of_files[self.index])
        while not img.shape[0]:
            self.index += 1
            img = cv2.imread(self.list_of_files[self.index])            
        self.cv_img = img
        img_small = cv2.resize(img, (0,0), fx = IMAGE_RESIZE_FACTOR, fy = IMAGE_RESIZE_FACTOR)
        b, g, r = cv2.split(img_small)
        img_small = cv2.merge((r,g,b))
        im = Image.fromarray(img_small)
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im)       

    def resetCanvas(self):        
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.image, anchor="nw")
        self.canvas.configure(height = self.image.height(), width = self.image.width())
        self.canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0, height = self.image.height(), width = self.image.width())

    def initUI(self):
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        print "width and height of image should be ", self.image.width(), self.image.height()
        self.canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(self, width = self.image.width(), height = self.image.height())       
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.OnMouseDown)
        self.canvas.pack()

        nextButton = Button(self, text="Next", command=self.nextButton)
        nextButton.place(x=0, y=0)

        restartButton = Button(self, text="Restart", command=self.restart)
        restartButton.place(x=0, y=22)       

    def nextButton(self):
        new_img = self.cv_img[self.corners[0][1]/IMAGE_RESIZE_FACTOR:self.corners[1][1]/IMAGE_RESIZE_FACTOR, self.corners[0][0]/IMAGE_RESIZE_FACTOR:self.corners[1][0]/IMAGE_RESIZE_FACTOR]
        files = self.list_of_files[self.index].split("/")
        try:
            os.stat(POSITIVE_DIRECTORY+files[-2])
        except:
            os.mkdir(POSITIVE_DIRECTORY+files[-2])
        print("saving to ", "{}{}/{}".format(POSITIVE_DIRECTORY, files[-2], files[-1]))
        cv2.imwrite("{}{}/{}".format(POSITIVE_DIRECTORY, files[-2], files[-1]), new_img)
        self.saveNegatives(files)
        self.restart()
        self.loadImage()
        self.resetCanvas()

    def saveNegatives(self, files):
        low_x = min(self.corners[0][0], self.corners[1][0])/IMAGE_RESIZE_FACTOR
        high_x = max(self.corners[0][0], self.corners[1][0])/IMAGE_RESIZE_FACTOR
        low_y = min(self.corners[0][1], self.corners[1][1])/IMAGE_RESIZE_FACTOR
        high_y = max(self.corners[0][1], self.corners[1][1])/IMAGE_RESIZE_FACTOR

        try:
            os.stat(NEGATIVE_DIRECTORY+files[-2])
        except:
            os.mkdir(NEGATIVE_DIRECTORY+files[-2])

        new_img = self.cv_img[ :low_y, :]
        cv2.imwrite("{}{}/{}{}".format(NEGATIVE_DIRECTORY, files[-2], "LY", files[-1]), new_img)
        new_img = self.cv_img[ high_y: , :]
        cv2.imwrite("{}{}/{}{}".format(NEGATIVE_DIRECTORY, files[-2], "HY", files[-1]), new_img)

        new_img = self.cv_img[ :, :low_x ]
        cv2.imwrite("{}{}/{}{}".format(NEGATIVE_DIRECTORY, files[-2], "LX", files[-1]), new_img)
        new_img = self.cv_img[:,  high_x: ]
        cv2.imwrite("{}{}/{}{}".format(NEGATIVE_DIRECTORY, files[-2], "HX", files[-1]), new_img)


    def restart(self):
        self.corners = []
        self.index -=1
        self.canvas.delete("all")
        self.loadImage()
        self.resetCanvas()


    def OnMouseDown(self, event):
        print(event.x, event.y)
        self.corners.append([event.x, event.y])
        if len(self.corners) == 2:
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.corners[0][0], self.corners[0][1], self.corners[1][0], self.corners[1][1], outline ='cyan', width = 2)


def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x150+300+300")

    list_of_files = []
    file_names = []
    walker = iter(os.walk(IMAGE_DIRECTORY))
    next(walker)
    for dir, _, _ in walker:
        files = [dir + "/" +  file for file in os.listdir(dir)]            
        list_of_files.extend(files)
        file_names.extend(os.listdir(dir))

    list_of_processed_files = []
    processed_file_names = []
    walker = iter(os.walk(POSITIVE_DIRECTORY))
    next(walker)
    for dir, _, _ in walker:
        files = [dir + "/" +  file for file in os.listdir(dir)]            
        list_of_processed_files.extend(files)
        processed_file_names.extend(os.listdir(dir))

    good_names = set(file_names) - set(processed_file_names)
    list_of_files = [f for i, f in enumerate(list_of_files) if file_names[i] in good_names] 

    app = Example(root, list_of_files, IMAGE_DIRECTORY+"positives")
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [similar post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/23423/tool-to-label-images-for-supervised-classification) with suggestions to useful labeling/annotation tools with your requirements - browsing through images in a folder, drawing a rectangle around area of interest, saving the output coordinates to a file. Additional features are labeling, like "positive", "negative", "car", "dog", etc.

My favourite tools are:

- [Imglab](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/imglab)
- [Computer Vision Annotation Tool (CVAT)](https://github.com/opencv/cvat)
- [Label_BoundingBox](https://github.com/danFromTelAviv/bounding-box-labeler-yolo)